# Calculating Reflectance from Parrot Sequoia DN

Tags: convert, reflectance

I am dealing with the images of a Parrot Sequoia. I could not pre-process the images in Pix4d because I took single shots in different parts (so there are not overlapping images).. for me it is important to have reflectance values

For me still not clear WHAT do I need to read and from WHERE/HOW to calculate reflectance.. I georeferenced them in python and I was thinking that I could also calculate reflectance there.. I saw this approach https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/292426/122737  but I would like to know if somebody knows where/how to find such information